# Error: iterable expected, not decimal.Decimal - Problems while writing into csv

Tags: python, export-to-csv, pyodbc

As in the title. How do I convert the sql import into something usefull.
I of cause see that it is separate with commas which rings a lot of bells but...
Im new in regards to Python, I have mostly used Matlab and R.

I think that i have triede multiple things now to make it into a table with 7 columns.

First column is the UTC time for the observation. second the observation. third the observed asset (4 in all). Fourth time local time. then Hour local time, minute local time and Date local time.

```
import pyodbc
import csv
conn = pyodbc.connect("connection string"
        )
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''Commandstring''')

data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print(f'{row}')
    print()


with open('dataTester.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a= csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for row in data:
        a.writerows(row)
```

The print will show this result:

```
('2019-01-27 01:56:00.0000000', Decimal('1786.0000'), 90, '2:56', Decimal('2'), Decimal('56'), '2019-01-27')

('2019-01-27 01:57:00.0000000', Decimal('1786.0000'), 90, '2:57', Decimal('2'), Decimal('57'), '2019-01-27')

('2019-01-27 01:58:00.0000000', Decimal('1786.0000'), 90, '2:58', Decimal('2'), Decimal('58'), '2019-01-27')

('2019-01-27 01:59:00.0000000', Decimal('1786.0000'), 90, '2:59', Decimal('2'), Decimal('59'), '2019-01-27')
```

The end goal is to get it into a table. Then separate that one into four tables separate tables, one for each Asset (asset 90 being one of them).

[Click here to see screen shot. Im not allowed to post an actual image yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Jec.png)

Can anyone give a few hints. Especially on how to make it into at table I.

[Second - one level deeper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu9i8.png)

> From Comments:
>
> Writing to `csv` gives an error message:
>
> ```
> a.writerows(row) Error: iterable expected, not decimal.Decimal
> ```
>
> And the csv only contains one row with something like what should perhaps be the first column:
>
> ```
> 2,0,1,9,-,0,1,-,2,7, ,0,2,:,0,0,:,0,0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
> ```

Comment: it gives an error message regarding the last line:
    a.writerows(row)

Error: iterable expected, not decimal.Decimal

Comment: And the csv only contains one row with something like what should perhaps be the first column:
2,0,1,9,-,0,1,-,2,7, ,0,2,:,0,0,:,0,0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: `writerows` -> `writerow` or drop the loop.

Comment: wow that worked... Thanks! It jumps over a line each time it creates a new line. Can you see the reason why?

Comment: Solved: I did the change that Andras said and wrote the csv generator with lineterminator ="\n' to create the correct line terminator.
    with open('dataTester6.csv', 'w') as fp:
        a= csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
         for row in data:
            a.writerow(row)

Comment: @TheFrederik - Please consider posting your solution as an answer so that others can more easily benefit. Here on SO it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.